# React Router remounting component for the same route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```js
<Switch>
     <Route path='/deposit' component={DepositComponent} />
     <Route path='/withdraw' component={Withdraw} />
     <Route path='/messages/:convoId?' component={MessagesComponent} />
     <Route exact path='' render={(routeProps) => <MainContent {...this.props} {...routeProps} />} />
 </Switch>
```

In the MessagesComponent route whenever i change the route from /messages to /messages/:convoId the component remounts. I dont think it should remount since it's the same path and Route component.

Comment: [It doesn't remount in this simple example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zn97q3n614). Maybe there is something else going on in the component this is rendered in?

Comment: i see, thanks very much for that @Tholle